# How to set a default template in a ListView control

Tags: c#, asp.net, vb.net, listview, webforms

I have a ListView control with an `ItemTemplate`, and an `EditItemTemplate`. By default, the `ItemTemplate` is rendered; how can I change that? More clearly, on Page_Load, I would like my `EditItemTemplate` to be the selected template.

```
<asp:ListView ID="lvExample" runat="server" SelectMethod="GetStuff" UpdateMethod="UpdateStuff">
    <EditItemTemplate>
      ...
    </EditItemTemplate>

    <EditItemTemplate>
      ...
    </EditItemTemplate>
 </asp:ListView>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use this approach.
(1) Write your Edit logic/Edit Template in your inside you item template.
(2) Then you can put your ItemTemplate content into another template.

since the default load template is ItemTemplate you get your edit template load first since the content of your itemteplate is your edit template